# Write float numbers to File

Tags: java, java-io

I have floating point numbers in two files. I want to write them in to single file. When I open the file after writing, I cannot see the floating point numbers. I can see some machine code or something. Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class F
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fr1 = new FileInputStream("distance.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr1)); 
    FileInputStream fr2 = new FileInputStream("price.txt"); 
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr2));
    FileOutputStream fw1 = new FileOutputStream("file1.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(fw1);
    DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(bos); 
    String s1,s2;
    while(((s1 = br1.readLine()) != null) && ((s2=br2.readLine())!=null))
    {
        float a1=Float.parseFloat(s1);
        float a2=Float.parseFloat(s2);
        a1=a1*10;
        a2=a2*10000;
        System.out.println(a1+" "+a2);
        dos.writeFloat(a1);
        dos.writeFloat(a2);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us the file, what you expect to see, and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `DataOutputStream.writeFloat`? It sounds like you were expecting a *text* representation.

Comment: Since you are using `DataOutputStream`, the contents of the file are not human readable.

Comment: I want to see the numbers in text file after writing.

Comment: @user2133404 Then use a text based writer.

Comment: @RahulBobhate which stream to use so that contents can be read?

Comment: @user2133404, As Peter Lawrey suggested, you can use any `Writer` like `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Are you sure you need them to be human-readable? It would be safer to write them as binary using writeFloat().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the float in a binary format.

Note: DataInput/OutputStream is for binary formats and Reader/Writers are for text formats.

I suggest you use a PrintWriter to write text.

BTW You can use FileReader instead of FileInputStream and InputStreamReader.